# Unity3D - failed Build Android AppBundle using Gradle

Tags: java, android, maven, unity-game-engine, gradle

currently, my game builds successfully if build using Unity's `Internal` System. Now because I need `AppBundle` over `APK` I try to change build system to `Gradle` like below picture:

[image]

However, in `Gradle` it returns an error.

> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [{name=com.google.android.gms.play-services-drive-11.0.4, ext=aar}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Note: I'm using Unity v2017.4.30f1

Any Idea to Solve?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Change your mainTemplate.gradle file to something like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work, try to find one that works with your unity version, if you updated unity, this file may become incompatible preventing you from making a gradle build.

An easy fix would be to **let unity autogenerate the mainTemplate.gradle** file for you, and then applying your changes on the new file:

1) Copy the current contents of  Assets/Plugins/Android/mainTemplate.gradle file.
(Or simply have source control to show you the diff)

2) Delete the  Assets/Plugins/Android/mainTemplate.gradle file.

3) In the Android Player Settings window -> Publishing Settings: Check the "Custom Gradle Template". That will generate a new  mainTemplate.gradle file for you.

4) Compare new file with the old one - and apply changes you need to the new file.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you please share the build.gradle that's failing to build.

However, just going by the error you received, could you please apply thew plugin "java-library" if not applied already?

Please apply the plugin for "allprojects" if it's a multi-module gradle project. Otherwise, it needs to be added for the root project.

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
```